# What does this "1" mean over the Chromium button in the Launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

I took a screenshot but I can't work out how to attach it. I think the words in the question itself do the trick. At least, I hope they do.

Comment: Can you upload the screenshot to a site like imgur and put the link here? Thanks!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/XYlqdGD.png

Yes I didn't think it through at the time. It's an active download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the Unity Launcher progress bar for active downloads

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I bet the `1` wasn't the only number showing up.

You most likely pressed the `Super` key (aka Windows key) while the launcher was visible.
The numbers are **shortcuts**. You can start the respective application by pressing `Super` and the number then.